# Grobner basis for an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

In an article I'm reading the author says that a certain set of polynomials is a basis for an ideal $I\subset \Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. However, I have only ever seen Groebner basis in the context of polynomial rings over a field. I also cannot find any sources discussing groebner bases over general rings, or even PIDs. Does anyone know of such a source? Or does anyone know if there are important differences between the characteristics of Groebner bases over PIDs vs Groebner bases over a field?

Comment: Can't you compute the grobner basis over $\mathbb Q$ and then clear the (finitely many) denominators?

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure that works... For example if we have $I=\langle 2x \rangle\subset \Bbb Z[x]$, then in $\Bbb Q[x]$ we have that $I=\langle x\rangle$, and this is a Groebner basis. However, $x\not\in I\subset \Bbb Z[x]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book *Gröbner bases* by Thomas Becker and Volker Weispfenning (on springer) has a chapter on Gröbner bases over other kinds of rings in the end.

But yeah, as mentioned in the comments, $\mathbb Z$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$ so it could probably be much easier than that.

Abstract:

> The material in this section is not needed for the remaining sections
>   of this chapter. Here, we will generalize the theory of Gröbner bases
>   to polynomial rings over principal ideal domains. We will show that
>   for every given finite subset F of such a polynomial ring, the
>   equivalence problem for the ideal Id(F) is solvable by means of a
>   Gröbner basis construction. The reduction relation will not in general
>   allow the computation of unique normal forms, but it will be such that
>   f ∈ Id(F) iff every normal form of f equals 0. This is good enough for
>   the solution of the equivalence problem (cf. Theorem 5.55). For
>   Euclidean domains that allow the computation of unique remainders, we
>   will even obtain a reduction relation with unique normal forms.

Edit:

Bernard beat me to it, but the book by Adams and Lostaunau (published by the AMS) has a chapter on it as well. That book is in general far more readable than the B&W book in my opinion! I couldn't remember the authors so I was looking through the bib file I used when I referenced it, but then Bernard reminded me. It is better recommendation I think!

Answer (score 2):

You also can take a look at chapter 4 of *An Introduction to Gröbner Bases*, by William W. Adams & Philippe Loustounau, Graduate Studies in Mathematics, vol. 1 (AMS Publications).

Comment: Haha, was just about to edit my post to include that book...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion too